# Consolidating Multiple Worksheets into Master List

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a project where I'll have 5 worksheets that I want to continually update to a Master List. Most examples of this I've been able to find involve creating a new master worksheet. Instead, I'd like to have a permanent Master list that doesn't get deleted. I've tried modifying some code I've found on my own and it works, except it duplicates the data when it copies to the Master List. Can anyone see what's going on?

```
Sub CopyFromWorksheets()
Dim wrk As Workbook 'Workbook object - Always good to work with object variables
Dim sht As Worksheet 'Object for handling worksheets in loop
Dim trg As Worksheet 'Master Worksheet
Dim rng As Range 'Range object
Dim colCount As Integer 'Column count in tables in the worksheets

Set wrk = ActiveWorkbook 'Working in active workbook

For Each sht In wrk.Worksheets
Next sht

 'We don't want screen updating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set trg = wrk.Worksheets("Master")

 'Get column headers from the first worksheet
 'Column count first
Set sht = wrk.Worksheets(1)
colCount = sht.Cells(1, 255).End(xlToLeft).Column
 'Now retrieve headers, no copy&paste needed
With trg.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, colCount)
    .Value = sht.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, colCount).Value
     'Set font as bold
    .Font.Bold = True
End With

 'We can start loop
For Each sht In wrk.Worksheets
     'If worksheet in loop is the last one, stop execution (it is Master worksheet)
    If sht.Index = wrk.Worksheets.Count Then
        Exit For
    End If
     'Data range in worksheet - starts from second row as first rows are the header rows in all worksheets
    Set rng = sht.Range(sht.Cells(2, 1), sht.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Resize(, colCount))
     'Put data into the Master worksheet
    trg.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value = rng.Value
Next sht
 'Fit the columns in Master worksheet
trg.Columns.AutoFit

 'Screen updating should be activated
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: In `Set rng  = sht.Range ...` line, `Resize` method needs an actual row size.

Comment: Thanks, but can you clarify what you mean by this?

Comment: `Resize(sht.Cells(65536,1).End(xlUp).Row - 2,colCount)`

Comment: Thanks! I made this change and it fixes the problem but now running the macro copies all data below the currently existing data in the Master sheet. How can I tweak this to make it automatically replace the data in the master sheet.

Comment: Change `trg.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)` to `trg.Cells(1,1)` or whatever row the data starts on.